# Factorizing a linear map through another one that has a smaller kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $E,F,G$ be 3 vectors spaces and 
$U \in L(E,F)$, $W \in L(E,G)$.

Show that if $\ker(U)$ is included in $\ker(W)$ then there is a linear map $V \in L(F,G)$ such that $W=U\circ V$.

If $U$ is bijective then it's simple to write $V=W\circ U^{-1}$. But how can I find $V$ if $U$ is not bijective ?

Comment: Did you try to use some nice basis of $F$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Do you mean dimension ?

Comment: No, I mean a basis. If you want to define a linear map $V:F\to G$ and you have a basis $f_1,\dots,f_n$ of $F$ then it is enough to define $V(f_1),\dots,V(f_n)$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. So i must talk about $Im(F)$?

Comment: If you mean $Im(U)$, then yes. (Also, you want $W=V\circ U$, right? $U\circ V$ doesn't make sense given the domains and codomains here.)